# asp mvc 2 partial rendering

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i want to partialrender some control for example.
her my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#datetime").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data:
                {
                    datetime: dateText
                },
                url: '<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/ExcelToHtml") %>',
                async: true,
                success: function (response) { $('#report').html(response) }
            });
        }
        });
</script>
<div id="report">   
</div>
```

here server code:

```
public PartialViewResult ExcelToHtml(DateTime datetime) {
        ViewData["datetime"] = datetime;
        return PartialView("ExcelToHtml");
    }
```

now, i want to see my date, in div(id=report), but i dont see it.
thats just example, can not understand where am i wrong?

and the control ExcelToHtml.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<% ViewData["datetime"].ToString(); %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I just wanted to point out that you don't need to specify the view name when it is the same as the action name...

```
public PartialViewResult ExcelToHtml(DateTime datetime) {
    ViewData["datetime"] = datetime;
    return PartialView();
}
```

Secondly, to check your mechanism works, just put a placeholder on the partial view with nothing else...

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

I think that it is likely that you will see "Hello World" loaded into the div.

This leads onto the next point - can you share the code for the view - as I think the error is most likely to be in there.

Comment: I thought it might - so what do you do on the view as the problem is most likely an error that means nothing is returned via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to just return the datetime as json if that's all you need to return?

But, let's start.

1. Does your ExcelToHtml method get called when you select a date? Did you try to set a breakpoint there to see if it gets called?
2. What does the Partial View ExcelToHtml have? I don't see you trying to do anything in the success event of the $.ajax. There you should probably do: `$('#report').html(response);`

Try this out. Let me know if **1** is true and what happens in **2**.

Comment: i know that i can use json, but i want to understand the mechanism

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery change:

```
$('#report').html(response)
```

into:

```
$('#report').html(response.responseText)
```

And see if you now get actual HTML returned and inserted into your DIV